# POST returns 404 Not Found

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I've recently started using MEAN Stack to create a basic application, so im a total beginner, I set up my controllers and everything and I want to post, however it returns api/user not found, can someone pinpoint the problem and help me out? Thanks.

Server.js:

```
var app = require ('./app/app');
var signupController  = require ('./server/signup-controller');

app.post('api/users', signupController.create);
app.listen('8080', function(){

    console.log('[OK] => HTTP Server listening on http://localhost:8080');
    require('./app/db').init('mongodb://localhost:27017/shopialmedia' );
});
```

Server side Controller (signup-controller.js):

```
module.exports.create = function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
}
```

Client Side Controller (signup-controller.js):

```
app.controller('signupController', ['$scope', '$resource', function ($scope, $resource) {
    var User = $resource('/api/users');

    $scope.createUser = function () {
        var user = new User();
        user.email = $scope.userEmail;
        user.password = $scope.userPass;
        user.firstName = $scope.userFName;
        user.lastName = $scope.userLName;
        user.age = $scope.userAge;
        user.$save(function (result){
            $scope.user.push(result);
            $scope.userEmail = '';
            $scope.userPass = '';
            $scope.userFName = '';
            $scope.userLName = '';
            $scope.userAge = '';
        });
    }
}]);
```

My module :

```
var app = angular.module('signupApp', ['ngResource']);
```

My app.js :

```
var express = require ('express');
var app = express();


app.use(express.static('public'));
require('./routes')(app);

module.exports = app;
```

When I go to run the application on my web page and submit the information, it returns api/user 404 Not found any suggestions on what to do, I'd greatly appreciate it. As I said im a beginner so please take that into consideration.

Comment: Where is your get route that's your problem... You have a router which takes the path of post but I don't see the controller.list being called when you make a GET request to /api/users... Angular $resource thinks that you have something at the get path... for /users

Comment: If you're a "total beginner" then I suggest you to write apps from scratch so you know what things you write do.

Comment: @Zargold can you tell me what to write? I don't quite understand.

Comment: @Nonemoticoner I am trying dude, i've been testing alot of stuff but I've been on this post error for the whole day and I don't know why it's not working, and it's pretty frustrating.

Comment: Omar see what I wrote you but it looks to me like you have a while to go, watch a few MEAN stack tutorial videos, read some articles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server.js Add:

```
app.get('api/users', signupController.list);
```

signup-controller.js Add:

```
  mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  User = mongoose.model('User');
module.exports.list = function(req, res){
var searcher = req.query || {};
User.find(searcher)
.sort('-created')
  .exec(function (err, users) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).send({
        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
      });
    }

    res.json(users);
  });
  };
```

Obviously, you'll also have to connect to mongoose with a file probably called main.js then you'll need a UserModel.js (or equivalent) where you can define the attributes of your user etc using the mongoose Schema...

I mean you're missing a lot if you want something a little simpler to start you can just do:

```
module.exports.list = function(req, res){
    var users = [];
    res.json(users);
  };
```

Also think you need this and this is also nicer formatting:

```
  var router = express.Router();
  router.route('/')
    .get(users.list)
    .get(users.create)
  app.use('/api/users', router);
```

Not sure what this is supposed to do or what ./routes is: `require('./routes')(app);`

Comment: Thank you so much man for your effort, this didn't quite fix the problem so i completely revamped the design of my package and it worked out. Thanks for putting up with my clumsy code, and your patience.